# How to make a video from the photos running from the bottom up

Tags: video, ffmpeg, pictures, slideshow

I have 10 family photos. I want to use the FFMPEG command to create a video slideshow where the images run from the bottom up. How can I do it?

I used this command, however, the received video was only zoomed from the center, while I wanted the image to run from bottom to top:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 1/5 -f concat -safe 0 -i "E:\ffmpeg\list.txt" -filter_complex "zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0032,5)':d=125:x='iw/1.7777-(iw/zoom/1.7777)':y='ih/1.7777-(ih/zoom/1.7777)'" -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast E:\ffmpeg\VIDEO\out.mp4
```

Comment: Are the photos the same resolution?

Comment: I used this command, however, the received video was only zoomed from the center, while I wanted the image to run from bottom to top:  

ffmpeg -y -r 1/5 -f concat -safe 0 -i "E:\ffmpeg\list.txt" -filter_complex "zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0032,5)':d=125:x='iw/1.7777-(iw/zoom/1.7777)':y='ih/1.7777-(ih/zoom/1.7777)'" -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast E:\ffmpeg\VIDEO\out.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are 10 photos of the same resolution,

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt
       -vf tile=1x10,loop=1249:1:0,crop=iw:ih/10:0:clip((t-2.5)/5*ih/10,0,ih*9/10)
       -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast out.mp4
```

The tile filter assembles the images into 1 column x 10 rows.

The loop filter provides 1250 frames (original + 1249 copies) i.e. 10 pics x 25 fps x 5 seconds/image.

The crop filter simulates a bottom-to-top pan effect, taking 5 seconds to move from one image to another. The pan starts at 2.5 seconds and so the last image is fully shown at 47.5 seconds.

Comment: ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i "E:\ffmpeg\list.txt" -vf "tile=1x10,loop=1249:1:0,crop=iw:ih/10:0:clip(ih*9/10-((t-2.5)/5)*ih/10,0,ih*9/10)" -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast E:\ffmpeg\VIDEO\out1.mp4

I've tried your code and it returned an error like this: 

[AVFilterGraph @ 00000000006286c0] No such filter: '0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!

Comment: Your shell requires escaped commas: change `ih/10,0,ih*9/10` to `ih/10\,0\,ih*9/10`

Comment: Thank you it was running fine, however I like to picture it will run from bottom to top, then how?

Comment: It does scroll from bottom to top.

Comment: Yes that's right, I like to picture it will roll from the bottom uptop. the present code on it is run from the top down

Comment: Share your output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79127/discussion-between-ffmpeg-fans-and-gyan).

Comment: You can see at this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FEzUdfrjvdpWT_Ag-2ec1gomUuTaWxNT/view

Comment: Changed direction of motion. Check that your input is 10 frames of same resolution.

Comment: all pic frames 1024 x 768

Comment: specifically uncovered redirected motion here is the command? crop=iw:ih/10:0:clip(ih*9/10-((t-2.5)/15)*ih/10\,0\,ih*9/10

Comment: Yes, that's the change.

Comment: I have changed many of the "CROP" that it does not have the effect to switch reverse running slide pic, please help me?

Comment: Do you want to change the order of the pics?

Comment: I only want It does scroll from bottom to top.